# How is API request body created?

Tags: .net, api, rest

I have this put API.

URL looks like this : /v1/xp/generalUsers/{generalUserId}/users/{userId}/apps

but Request body looks like this :

```
  {
  "connectedApps": [
    {
      "connectedAppId": "string",
      "applicationRoles": [
        {
          "roleId": "string",
          "assignedResources": [
            {
              "resourceType": "string",
              "resourceId": "string",
              "resourceHint": "string",
              "resources": [
                null
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I have another API call which demands the same exact parameters. But, I do not know its Request body.

I'm interested how and where is this JSON structure built.
In code(.Net), I can only find the parameters that are passed to API call. I'm building URI and passing it.

I don't have Swagger for it.

To summarize,

- How can I find the request body of the API call and how is it built?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you are trying to use an API created by someone else.

You can ask for API documentation to get the request and response structure and type. Or if you have the code with you you can check the API call and see the parameters.

You can use Swagger - it will  Generates the API documentation.

For Http Get : You can  pass the parameters through the url query string

`http://example.com/path1/path?actualparametername = value`

Http Post : You have to provide more details. Such as request body.
You can use a REST Client for testing. example Postman.

```
   You should provide content-type and body as input.

   The structure of request json depends on the API. You can check your API and create a request json matching the class structure used as parameter.
```

Example :

```
Class Person{
 string name;
 int age;
}
```

ApiAction(Person p)

Then your  Request Json will look like

```
{
"name":"Yourname",
"age": 28
}
```

For Complete Reference.

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: my c# code for one of api calls looks like this 
                        GenericResponse<Role> gr = await new HttpAPIClient().Put<Role>(role, uri); 

Does that mean that I am passing Role object in a body?